# How to make a biased random number out of a large set of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to make Python 3.7.1 pick a number between 0 and 100.  However I want a lower number to be much more likely than a higher number, in a reverse exponential-smooth-graduation-curve kind of way (doesn't have to be exact).

I guess I could start with

```py
myrandomnumber = random.randint(0, 100)
```

And then link that to an array of some sort to determine differing percentages for each number.  I've seen other people do that with random die rolls, but the thing is, that's quite neat for only for six possibilities, I want to do this for a hundred (or more) and don't want to sit there making a huge array with a hundred entries just for that.  Of course I could do it this way I suppose, but I feel like Python probably has a really easy way to do this that I'm missing.

Thanks, folks!

Comment: What did you try? It is always better to have a starting point to help you :)

Comment: Learn about the fundamental mathematics of sampling from distributions randomly. You are already familiar with sampling from the *uniform* distribution, and probably the *normal* distribution. What about histograms, betas, circles, spheres, annuli, and so on? ("Monte Carlo" is a good term to become familiar with.)

Comment: You seem to be asking for integer outcomes bounded between 0 and 100 inclusive.  Is that correct, or are continuous (float based) distributions okay?  Could the upper end be unbounded but rare, or is a fixed upper bound a requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is a [**gamma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) distributed random number.

For example with a *`k=1`* and *`θ=2.0`*:

[image]

There are algorithms for using the evenly-distributed `random` function to generate `normal`, `exponential`, or `gamma` distributed values.

But since you're in python, you could probably jump straight to using numpy's [`random.gamma`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html) function:

```
#the (1,2) shape ends basically at 20. Multiply by 5 to get my 0..100 scale
numpy.random.gamma(1, 2.0) * 5
```

Comment: I get the impression that OP is looking for a discrete distribution on a bounded interval, given the "starting point" was `randint(0,100)`.  Gammas are continuous and have infinite support.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  I used this and then used the 'result = round(myrandomnumber)' to convert to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with the assumption that you want to generate integer values over a bounded range, and that you mean non-uniformly distributed when you talk about "bias".  Since you don't have a particular parametric distribution in mind, one approach is to start with a continuous distribution and take the "floor" of the outcomes using `int()`.  You'll want to increase the upper bound by 1 so that rounding down gives values inclusive of that bound.

One easy choice is a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution). Python provides `random.triangular()` function, which takes 3 arguments—the lower bound, upper bound, and the mode.  Here's a discretized version:

```
import random as rnd
import math
import sys

def triangle(upper_bound):
    return int(rnd.triangular(0.0, float(upper_bound + 1) - sys.float_info.epsilon, 0.0))
```

I've subtracted float's epsilon from the upper bound to prevent the (extremely unlikely) chance of getting an outcome of 101 when your upper bound is 100.  Another bounded distribution choice might be the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), which you could then scale and truncate.

If you want the distribution shifted even further down the scale towards 0, you could use distributions such as the [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), or more generally the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), with truncation and rounding.  Both of those have infinite support, so there are a couple of ways to truncate.  The simpler way is to use [acceptance/rejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)—keep generating values until you get one in range:

```
def expo_w_rejection(upper_bound, scale_param = 0.4):
    upper_bound += 1
    while True:
        candidate = rnd.expovariate(1.0 / (upper_bound * scale_param))
        if candidate < upper_bound:
            return int(candidate)
```

As before, bump the upper limit up by 1 to get outcomes that include the upper limit after truncating.  I've also included an optional `scale_param` which should be a value strictly between 0 and 1, i.e., not inclusive of either limit.  Values closer to 0 will cause the results to bunch more to the left, values closer to 1 yield less bunching.

The other method would be to use the inverse transform technique for generating, and to restrict the range of the uniform to not exceed the upper bound based on evaluating the cumulative distribution function at the target upper bound:

```
def trunc_exp(upper_bound, scale_param = 0.4):
    upper_bound = float(upper_bound) + 1.0 - sys.float_info.epsilon
    trunc = 1.0 - math.exp(-1.0 / scale_param)
    return int((-upper_bound * scale_param) * math.log(1.0 - trunc * rnd.random()))
```

Both approaches yield distributionally simular results, as can be seen in the following screenshot.  "Column 1" was generated with truncated inversion, while "Column 2" was generated with acceptance/rejection.

[image: Histograms and summary statistics for truncated exponentials generated by inversion and acceptance/rejection]

Comment: This is great, thank you!  However it's a little bit over my head mathematically.  I'll keep these examples in mind if I need to alter the distribution.  Thank you!